# Umbraco backoffice not loading packages

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This all of sudden started happening the other day, the backoffice in my umbraco installation has stopped loading the packages. This is because the content is trying to be loaded over http opposed to https so its getting blocked. Does's anyone have any idea why this is happening? Or have a things to check/ a hack to get it working again just so i can install Courier and move the content to another installation cleanly.

I am using v7.4.3

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've had a similar situation when I added addititional security settings to my Umbraco installation, did you do any changes to customHeaders in the web.config?

Comment: No, theres not customHeaders set.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a know issue same to this 
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8141

It is fixed in umbraco 7.5 according to the issue tracking

I will suggest local install Courier via zip or temporary disable https

Comment: Ended up ditching umbraco, too much hassle moving around installations/content to different environments even with courier.

Comment: IMO umbraco is pretty good in general usage, but you are right, it does cause a lot of pain when moving content around envrionement